# ContentPlaceHolder in Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I can use ContentPlaceHolder's with Webforms view engines to put stuff in different locations in the master page.

How do I do that with Razor?

```
    <div id="content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div> 
    <div id="footer">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Footer" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

Comment: Answer by @jgauffin is good enough , but following is also a well written post by Scott Gu which explains in detail about how sections work http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yet again I managed to ask before finding the correct search keywords in Google.

In the layout

```
@RenderSection("footer", required: false)
```

View example

```
<h2>About</h2> 

<p>   
    Some stuff about this page.   
</p> 

<p> 
    The current date and time: @DateTime.Now  
</p> 

@section footer { 

    Copyright (c) 2010, Robert Sundström. 

}
```

Comment: BTW in MVC 3 RC the parameter to `RenderSection` changed from `optional` to `required` (and its meaning reversed, of course). So, it would look like this: @RenderSection("footer", required: false) (I edited the answer to reflect this.)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. thanks for this question and answer :)

Comment: why we give rendersection as false?

Comment: @Duk, it's given as `false` to indicate that no content should render. So in the case where the user does not do (as in the example above) `@section footer { ... }`, then nothing is displayed. Try it out without that last bit of code, you will see nothing is rendered. But if you add it (like the example above), then the Copyright get's rendered.

Answer (score 10):

Couldn't leave a comment sorry but you can remove the "required:"

```
@RenderSection("footer", false)
```

Comment: I like the "required" being there; it makes the code instantly understandable

Comment: at first when i saw this required i was confused, because well its not normal to pass the name of the parameter so its "instantly understandable". then why people dont like hungarian notations? it makes all your code understandable:)

Comment: @Kyle: Because "true" doesn't say as much as `"footer"`. `true` could represent anything but most of us understand what the `"footer"` is in a method called `RenderSection`