# Generic view in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Good morrow,

I am learning about razor, and found myself stuck in a problem.

Although i know how to use inheritance with cshtml file with an actual class, "`@inherits BasicListView<UserModel>`", I wanted to have all the comodities of the cshtml template engine, to make a base view, like a generic listing view, per instance.

I believe that one might not be able to directly, cshtml to cshtml, mark an inheritance, but it is quite ok, as it will become a class anyway.

As well, i could generate the class by myself and then use it's object, i may be wrong, but sounds a little too workaround for me.

Would anyone care of having an elegant solution for it?

Edit:
I will redo the question:

Keeping in mind that there is a strongly-typed view, for per example a list page, can anyone think on how to implement a generic-typed view, for the same porpouse?

Comment: Hi. It us unclear what you are asking for. Could you revise your question and provide more details on the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're view would either need to work off a common interface e.g.

```
@inherits BasicListView<IMyModel>
```

Or use dynamic:

```
@inherits BasicListView<dynamic>
```

Comment: That would resolve the first problem of having a generic view, but the idea was having something that i could extend a little. And some view that would be specific make use of it. I was thinking on having the code generated, and then, by dependency injection, its class inserted in a view. I am cracking my head over that. It shouldn't be so hard... I wish i could generate the view, on the RenderPartial method, passing some type, as it's parameter...

Comment: Is there something that resembles the asp:contentplaceholder in razor?

Comment: there is!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163429/contentplaceholder-in-razor