# What's a good way to do meta tags in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a master layout page with a default title, and meta content. How can I override the title and meta content in child pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way that works for now. I'm wure it can be improved, but this is the closet thing to an ideal solution that I have come across.

In the controllers assign whatever meta info you need for that view.

```
ViewBag.Title = "some title";
ViewBag.MetaDescription = "some description";
etc...
```

and in the master layout page I do the following

```
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>    

    @if(ViewBag.MetaDescription != null)
    {
        <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.MetaDescription" />
    }

    @if(ViewBag.MetaKeywords != null)
    {
        <meta name="keywords" content="@ViewBag.MetaKeywords" />
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

define a [ContentPlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx) ([@RenderSection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163429/contentplaceholder-in-razor) in Razor) and fill it in the views that use the master page, using Content (@section in Razor).

Comment: How do I define default values?

Comment: You can just fill in the sections in the master page.  If you fill them in the children it replaces the default.  For Razor, it's a little more difficult: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2010/12/08/optional-razor-sections-with-default-content.aspx